# Finding all possible solution candidates in Scipy and its Linprog?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I use Scipy to find maximum independent sets like [here](http://yaroslavvb.blogspot.fi/2011/03/linear-programming-for-maximum.html) such that

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

c=[1,1,1,1]
A=[[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0]];
b=[1,1,1,1]
print(opt.linprog([-a for a in c],A_ub=A,b_ub=b))
```

where consider a cycle graph `C_4` so a solution is `[1,0,1,0]` corresponding

```
     fun: -2.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 2
   slack: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])
```

[image]

where the first vertex and the third vertex selected. Other solution that is missing is `[0,1,0,1]`, how can I get that?

In more general way,

**How can I get all possible solution candidates to a LP problem in Scipy?**

Comment: Rigorously finding all optimal solutions is not possible with a basic LP algorithm. You can encode the basis using binary variables, and then use a series of MIP models (see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html)).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can you demonstrate the approach taken there with this  very simple cycle graph C4? So you would formulate different basis/constraints here to two different answers here? How is MIP approach related to this?

Comment: (1). Yes it works. I get `x=(1,0,1,0)` and `x=(0,1,0,1)`. (2) I don't understand your second question (3) I encode the basis using binary variables: `0=nonbasic`, `1=basic`. We cannot have something in between. Note that you can also simplify things by considering your problem directly as a MIP (`x(i) binary`) and use the same integer cut strategy described in the link (or use the solution pool technology available in advanced mip solvers). If this all sounds too complicated then just use my basic answer: no you cannot enumerate all optimal LP solutions using `linprog`.